# Is there a difference between x.f.call(x, ...) and x.f(...)?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some code that looks like

```
this.f.call(this);
```

Or in some other cases

```
this.someObj.f.call(this.someObj);
```

Is there any difference between these and

```
this.f();
this.someObj.f();
```

Are there any circumstances where the behavior would be different?  (For example, is the behavior different if `this` or `someObj` is null or isn't actually an object, or `f` isn't actually a function?  I can't think of a way where one would throw an exception and the other wouldn't, but maybe I'm missing something...)

EDIT: To clarify: yes, I know that `.call` can be used to specify the `this` value seen by the function, and it can be useful in cases where you can't use the `obj.f()` syntax (because `f` isn't a property of `obj` or you don't know whether it is). My question isn't about how `.call` works in general.  My question is about **this** case, where I can't see an obvious reason for using `.call` as opposed to the object-property syntax.

Comment: Yes, these change the _this_ value. Namely to generify methods, for example you can use `.call` to use array methods on a DOM `NodeList`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please elaborate... I know that `x.f.call(x)` will set this `this` value seen inside the function to `x`, but doesn't `x.f()` do exactly the same thing?  What do you mean by "these change the `this` value?"  I'll edit the question to clarify...

Comment: So don't pass `this` in, pass something else. For example `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("a"),function(link){ console.log(link.href);});` will spit out all the links in the page even though the return value of `querySelectorAll` - a NodeList does not have a forEach method.

Comment: I've edited this question to explain why it is **not** a duplicate.  Please unmark it.  Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: But then the example wouldn't serve to explain his question.  He's asking if there's any difference between `x.f(...)` and `x.f.call(x, ...)`.

Comment: @intuited Ok, if we understand it this way then there is no difference between the two in implementations that abide to the language spec.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: spec-compliant JS implementations having historically been relatives of Bigfoot, are there differences in other common implementations?  Inquiring minds want to know :)

Comment: Voting to reopen. The OP obviously understands how `call` works in general, and is confused because (s)he's seen code that seems to use it for no reason. A generic answer about how `call` works is not going to address that confusion.

Comment: @intuited And if I may be precise http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3 and http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4 show that they behave exactly the same. Surprisingly, most modern implementations are spec complaint one way or the other. There should be no difference between the two.

Comment: Especially on built-in types it can be a nice protection against overriding, i.e. a class has methods that override the `toString` method, you can use the original version via `Function.prototype.toString.call( instance.someMethod )`.

Comment: The answer to "is there a difference" is "no" and that's 28 characters short of the minimum an answer must have. The OP has gotten the answer so I don't see the point in reopening. If we had some context we might be able to speculate the reasons why someone would use `.call()` seemingly unnecessarily, but even that would take some work to make a good question.

Comment: @ajb: What **is** the context here?  Is the code targeting a specific implementation of JS?  If so, which one?  Any other contextual details that might be relevant?  Is it likely to be used in an environment (e.g. enterprise-maintained app deployment) where older browsers are in use?

Comment: @intuited It's in a [bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) plugin, and they're trying to be cross-browser compatible.  I don't have a clue why it was written that way.  The only thing I can think of is that there might be a difference if somehow `Function.prototype.call` got reassigned, but I sure hope they didn't do that (that's got to be on someone's "How to make your code totally unreadable" list).

Comment: You could dig through the commit history to find out who committed that particular line and try asking them.  `git log -p -S'this.f.call(this);' $FILENAME` should do it, although there might be something more convenient provided by github.  Note that the `-S` option uses regular expressions and that there should not be a space between the `S` and the `'`.

Comment: @ajb Can you show us the plugin itself? We might have better insight, note that I've had issues in the KnockoutJS codebase for example that ended up being code mash, or contributors not fully grasping subtleties. While your question about `.call` is/was definitely in place, I wouldn't think too much about why _they_ used `this.f.call(this)` as the only "interesting" case (that is, "unbinding" a `.bind`ed function) is still incorrect.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You can get the plugin by downloading from the github link in my previous comment and looking in `modal.js`.  I haven't yet had a chance to look through the history, but I will.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum OK, I did some digging... it looks like there was a call to `jQuery.proxy(this.hide, this)`, and someone needed to rearrange the timing of when `proxy` was called, and they changed the call to `this.hide.call(this)`.  Looks more like the contributor made a "mechanical" translation without realizing they could have simplified it, rather than thinking up some (incorrect) reason why they thought `.call` was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There is no difference between the two.

If we check the language specification for  [normal function calls](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3) and then [`Function.prototype.call`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4) we can see that they behave exactly the same.

Namely,

`x.f.call(x)` does this:

> Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of func, providing thisArg as the this value and argList as the list of arguments.

Where a normal call does:

> Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method on func, providing thisValue as the this value and providing the list argList as the argument values.

Where `this` has resolution (specified in 11.2.3 7.b.i in the spec).

All modern JavaScript implementations (yes, even IE8 modern) respect this.

Comment: They behave the same most of the times. One could do `someMethod.toString = function () { return "Psych!"; };`, but you could still get the original by using `Function.prototype.toString.call(someMethod);`. It doesn't work, though, if the prototype itself is overridden. To be fair, it also slightly differs from the original question (find the difference ;) )

Comment: That's not what I meant, but that was my fault. I edited my comment.

Comment: @IngoBürk Interesting point, however - this is only the case if you save the object's original `toString` beforehand and apply it to the object at a later point, I don't see how it could be done in an `x.f.call(x)` scenario without first saving `x.f` someplace else.

Comment: My point differs from the question in the sense that it's `x.f()` versus `x.prototype.f.call(x)`, not `x.f.call(x)`. I just recently had to use this, because a library overrides `toString` for class constructors, but I could get the original value using `Function.prototype.toString`.

Comment: Example (pretty similar to what I actually encountered): http://jsfiddle.net/UPUSE/

Comment: Are there historical implementations that did not follow this rule?  How recently?  How many people might still be using such implementations?

Comment: @intuited All popular browsers that were made in the last 14 years follow this rule, it's perfectly safe to assume you're working against an implementation that does this correctly.